# Testcafe Localhost behind has issues?

Tags: proxy, localhost, devexpress, testcafe

Using the latest version of Testcafe...

I'm behind a corporate proxy.  Using --proxy myproxy:proxyport works fine.  but when I try to use localhost, it continually responds with service not available.  I have now added --proxy-bypass localhost:8080.  But that has the same result.

Has anyone else experienced issues with Testcafe behind a corporate proxy -- and using localhost?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that localhost:8080 is incorrect. You need to set up your own port here.

In addition, you can simply use [the following record](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#--proxy-bypass-rules):

```
--proxy-bypass localhost
```

In this case, all localhosts will be ignored regardless of the port.

Comment: tx  Root cause was I was trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 and proxy-bypass had localhost.